# PHP cURL within a form

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to perform a cURL request within a form.  Basically I have a page called monitoringform.php results.php and curl.php.  When the user enters a MAC address into the form and presses submit, i would like the value of mac address to process through curl.php, obtain the result and post it in results.php.  The cURL function works fine but I cannot get it to POST to results.php  While I was playing around I noticed sometimes the IP shows up however it is incorrect.  Can it be old data from the session? Any help is greatly appreciated!

monitoringform.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<h3>Monitoring Request Form</h3>
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post">

<label for="regularInput">Modem MAC</label>
<input type="text" name="modemmac" id="modemmac"  />

<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit Form</button>

</form>
```

results.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
        include "curl.php";
        $mactosearch = $_POST['modemmac'];


        $mymessage=$_GET["message"];
    if($mymessage=="success")
        { 
          echo "<b>Modem IP Address:</b> $modemip <br />";
        }
        else{ echo "You are getting error";}
        ?>
```

curl.php

```
<?php    
        // Defining the basic cURL function
    function curl($url) {
        // Assigning cURL options to an array
        $options = Array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,  // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,  // Setting cURL to follow 'location' HTTP headers
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE, // Automatically set the referer where following 'location' HTTP headers
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,   // Setting the amount of time (in seconds) before the request times out
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,  // Setting the maximum amount of time for cURL to execute queries
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, // Setting the maximum number of redirections to follow
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8",  // Setting the useragent
            CURLOPT_URL => $url, // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
        );

        $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);   // Setting cURL's options using the previously assigned array data in $options
        $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable
        curl_close($ch);    // Closing cURL
        return $data;   // Returning the data from the function
    }


    // Defining the basic scraping function
    function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){
        $data = stristr($data, $start); // Stripping all data from before $start
        $data = substr($data, strlen($start));  // Stripping $start
        $stop = stripos($data, $end);   // Getting the position of the $end of the data to scrape
        $data = substr($data, 0, $stop);    // Stripping all data from after and including the $end of the data to scrape
        return $data;   // Returning the scraped data from the function
    }
    $scraped_page = curl("http://localhost?q_mac=$mactosearch&fields=only:ip");    
    $modemip = scrape_between($scraped_page, "<ip>", "</ip>");    
}
?>
```

Comment: What about `action="results.php"` ..? I might misunderstand...

Comment: I have this in the code as well, I didn't want to add too much to make it confusing.

    `if($result){header('Location: results.php?message=success'); }else{header('Location: results.php?message=error'); }`

Comment: You want both `results.php` and `curl.php` to use the POST data from the form? If you post to `results.php`, that's what happens. You do have to call the `curl()` function at some point though.